# Legality of being an extra/actor for Bollywood as a tourist?

Tags: india, uk-citizens, work, eu-citizens

I've heard on some websites ([including this one](https://www.orbitz.com/blog/2015/05/bollywood-film-extra)) how easy it may be to become an extra for a Bollywood film. Obviously, it involves being paid.

What's the legality of this for a tourist and can someone legally come to India to work in Bollywood as an extra or potentially even as an actor? As no one would probably want to be pulled out of a set and get deported...

Comment: Are you wanting to do this once because it's a fun thing to do while you are visiting India as a tourist, or are you trying to earn money as an extra and wanting to do it without getting a work visa?

Comment: I don't know about the author. I would be happy to do it for fun (: